# Tor, Mac Anonabox, Linksys switching networks

Tags: mac

So I run 2 wireless networks at my house. Both feed into a Charter Cable Modem. The 2 Networks are. A Linksys 5 port wireless router and a 1 port Anonabox that feeds into the Linksys. The problem is actually with the Tor Browser itself. I ran into this problem before and a user helped me but until now I wasn't able to narrow it down fully.
I have found that there are some websites that I cannot get to with the Tor Browser thru the Anonabox wifi. 
What's weird is that if I delete the "TorBrowser-Data" and then switch to the Anonabox wifi it works fine, and continues to work. It only doesn't work when I connect for the first time on the regular network, and then try to use the Anonabox it breaks. Then the only way to fix it is to delete the "TorBrowser-Data". Which I hate because I'm a rookie and I loose all my shit like bookmarks. Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: What do the Tor logs show?